# SQL to add a summary row to MySQL result set

Tags: mysql, sql, resultset, summary

If I have a MySQL table such as:

[image]

I want to use SQL to calculate the sum of the `PositiveResult` column and also the `NegativeResult` column. Normally I could simply do `SUM(PositiveResult)` in a query.

But what if I wanted to go a step further and place the totals in a row at the bottom of the result set:

[image]

Can this be achieved at the data level or is it a presentation layer issue? If it can be done by SQL, how might I do this? I am a bit of an SQL newbie.

Thanks to the respondents. I will now check things with the customer.

Also, can a text column be added so that the value of the last row of data is not shown in the summary row? Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would also do this in the presentation layer, but you *can* do it MySQL...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,pos DECIMAL(5,2)
,neg DECIMAL(5,2)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,0,0),
(2,1,-2.5),
(3,1.6,-1),
(4,1,-2);


SELECT COALESCE(id,'total') my_id,SUM(pos),SUM(neg) FROM my_table GROUP BY id WITH ROLLUP;

+-------+----------+----------+
| my_id | SUM(pos) | SUM(neg) |
+-------+----------+----------+
|     1 |     0.00 |     0.00 |
|     2 |     1.00 |    -2.50 |
|     3 |     1.60 |    -1.00 |
|     4 |     1.00 |    -2.00 |
|  total|     3.60 |    -5.50 |
+-------+----------+----------+
5 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Here's a hack for the amended problem - it ain't pretty but I think it works...

```
SELECT COALESCE(id,'') my_id
     , SUM(pos)
     , SUM(neg)
     , COALESCE(string,'') n
  FROM my_table 
 GROUP 
    BY id
     , string
  WITH ROLLUP
HAVING n <> '' OR my_id = ''
;
```

Comment: I agree better presentation level should handle grand total. You query gives perfect output!.

Comment: This is almost perfect. But if the table includes a text column, then the values of the last row of data are included in the summary row. Can that be overcome at all? I notice that `COALESCE` isn't actually necessary either.

Comment: If there is a text column, can the summary row display a blank or null for it?

Comment: I have posted the sort of thing I mean at the end of the original question.

Comment: Thanks. The presentation layer is still the tidiest approach anyway.

Comment: It seems to. I will see what the customer thinks.

Answer (score 0):

```
select keyword,sum(positiveResults)+sum(NegativeResults)
from mytable
group by
Keyword
```

if you need the absolute value put sum(abs(NegativeResults)

Answer (score 0):

This should be handled at least one layer above the SQL query layer.

The initial query can fetch the detail info and then the application layer can calculate the aggregation (summary row). Or, a second db call to fetch the summary directly can be used (although this would be efficient only for cases where the calculation of the summary is very resource-intensive and a second db call is really necessary - most of the time the app layer can do it more efficiently).

The ordering/layout of the results (i.e. the detail rows followed by the "footer" summary row) should be handled at the presentation layer.

Comment: I would agree but I will see what the customer decides.

Comment: I can sympathize :).  If your app development team and/or customer insists that one query return detail + summary, then you can use `UNION` or SQL Window Functions if available to do it all at once, **BUT** you'll have to make sure you create some kind of ordering so that the rows are returned in the correct way.  Don't **ever** rely on the db to give you rows back in a certain order without you explicitly specifying the exact order!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend doing this at the presentation layer. To do something like this in SQL is also possible.

```
create table test (
  keywordid int, 
  positiveresult decimal(10,2), 
  negativeresult decimal(10,2)
);
insert into test values 
(1, 0, 0), (2, 1, -2.5), (3, 1.6, -1), (4, 1, -2);

select * from (
    select keywordid, positiveresult, negativeresult
    from test
      union all
    select null, sum(positiveresult), sum(negativeresult) from test
) main
order by
case when keywordid is null then 1000000 else keywordid end;
```

I added ordering using a arbitrarily high number if keywordid is null to make sure the ordered recordset can be pulled easily by the view for displaying.

```
Result:
+-----------+----------------+----------------+
| keywordid | positiveresult | negativeresult |
+-----------+----------------+----------------+
|         1 |           0.00 |           0.00 |
|         2 |           1.00 |          -2.50 |
|         3 |           1.60 |          -1.00 |
|         4 |           1.00 |          -2.00 |
|      NULL |           3.60 |          -5.50 |
+-----------+----------------+----------------+
```